# How was Ben stung?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

Ben was a *Maze Runner* who attacked Thomas after Ben was stung by a Griever. The boys seem shocked that Ben was stung "during the day." If he was stung IN the maze then what was he doing back all ready; it was still early in the day. Why didn't anyone notice his incredibly early return. If he had been stung the day before then the reaction took time (which didn't seem to be the case in anyone else's experience). And when else could they have expected Ben to have been stung? Unless Grievers are walking through the Glade (and at that point, they weren't) the only time Ben would have been out would have been during the day -- he couldn't have gotten stung at night.

Comment: I don't understand how the Grievers were waling through the Glade at day because if the had, the Gladers would have seen them, it doesn't make any sense. I figure that Ben must have found the carcass of a dead griever somewhere in the maze, said to Minho he is checking something out and accidentally got stung, he then probably informed Minho that he believes he has been stung and told Minho to keep quiet about it just in case, they return to the Glade as quickly as possible and then Ben may have blacked out only to wake up only an hour or two later, he must have remembered everything and then

Comment: By the way, Ben was not a maze runner, he was a builder.

Answer (score 4):

In the books, the Gladers have the *Swipe* a microchip that allowed WCKD to wipe their memory ***AND*** control them directly. The second movie shows that the Gladers are chipped for identification, and implies that the chip is related to the memory loss, but nothing has implied that they control the Gladers. The Grievers are also shown in the movie to be controlled by WCKD electronically.

Either way, it would have been simple for WCKD to arrange for Ben to be stung, simply by having a single Griever attack quietly in the Glade. Keep in mind that WCKD has essentially unlimited funds and created the Maze from scratch. They could have easily built a tunnel for the purposes of forcing this event from the beginning. The entire Maze trial was planned out in detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you recall, Ben's condition prompted many Gladers to believe the Grievers **had** started walking through the glade, and they blamed that on Thomas's entering the maze when he wasn't a runner.

Comment: But the responses was "during the day?" which might indicate that grievers walk through the Glade at night but not the day. They didn't respond "but he wasn't in the maze."

Comment: it's more of a shock that Grievers are out during the day, as they are supposed to be 'housed' in daylight hours... more of a shock even that they had been in the glade..

Comment: If the grievers were walking in the Glade at ay, the Gladers would have seen them, or Gladers would just be simply disappearing because they might be 'picked' off and killed.